# How do I upgrade bootstrap in my mezzanine's project?

Tags: python, css, django, mezzanine

- Environments
  pc: mac os 10.13.1
- Versions
  python: 3.6.2
  mezzanine: 4.3.1
  django: 1.11.16
  bootstrap: 3.3.5  (confirmed in /{my_name}/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mezzanine/core/static/css/bootstrap.css)

Here, my mezzanine project has base.html for site interface. There is the code to get the css-code(design). That is bootstrap.css.

But the bootstrap.css relies to bootstrap3(3.3.5), and I have to use bootstrap4(4.0.0). (This is my boss's order.)

Then, I wanna get(download) bootstrap4, put it to right directory and change bootstrap dependency by linking to the directory which I put earlier.

How should I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This might break your things all the `classes` which are obsoleted will not work in newer version to get prevent this refactor all view files . Simple Solution is change the file in  `static/` and import the partials header or footer file linked

Comment: `static/` is in my mezzanine project? or in a mezzanine package?

Comment: `static` is a folder which contains `css`and `js` libraries

Comment: Sorry fo asking again and again.
Did you mean `{my_name}/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mezzanine/core/static` ?

Or

`{mezzanine_project}/static`?